# how to update response of spider in scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm very new to SCRAPY
I try to extract 100 quotes from this website (http://quotes.toscrape.com/random), to do this I write the following spider

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class QuotesProjectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
     name = 'quotes_project'
     allowed_domains = ['toscrape.com']
     start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/random']

    def parse(self, response):
         self.log('i gonna scrape : '+response.url)
         #self.log('the whole page : '+response.text)
         i=1
         tempQuotes = {}
         quotesArray = [ {
            'author' : response.css('div.quote small.author::text')[0].extract(),
            'quote' : response.css('div.quote span.text::text')[0].extract(),
            'tags' : response.css('div.quote div.tags a.tag::text').extract()
        }]
         flag = False
         while i < 100:
              tempQuotes =  {
            'author' : response.css('div.quote small.author::text')[0].extract(),
            'quote' : response.css('div.quote span.text::text')[0].extract(),
            'tags' : response.css('div.quote div.tags a.tag::text').extract()
        }
              flag = False
              j = 0
              n = len(quotesArray)
              while not flag and j < n :
                   if tempQuotes['quote'] == quotesArray[j]['quote'] :
                       flag = True
                   j+=1
              if not flag :
                   quotesArray.append(tempQuotes)
                   i+=1
              print("i = " + str(i))
              print("quote : "+tempQuotes['quote'])
              print("condition : " + str(tempQuotes['quote'] == quotesArray[0]['quote']))

    yield quotesArray
```

the problem here in this line

> print("condition : " + str(tempQuotes['quote'] == quotesArray[0]['quote']))

it shows me True with an infinite loop, that means the response is not updated, because the website shows a new quote every time you refresh the page, so how to update the response of parse function in each loop.
can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be handling the looping and counting logic in your `parse` method.
Instead, it should only handle extracting your item and making new requests.

This will extract an item and then reload the page.

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield {
        'author': response.css('div.quote small.author::text').get(),
        'quote': response.css('div.quote span.text::text').get(),
        'tags': response.css('div.quote div.tags a.tag::text').getall(),
    }

    yield response.request
```

To stop this from going on forever, you can use the [Close spider extension](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.extensions.closespider).
Setting either `CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT` or `CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT` should work for your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by stranac, the easiest way is to use the [close spider extension](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.extensions.closespider).

Your spider responsibility should be only to build items and requests.

Another problem in your code is the `[0].extract()`, you should use `.extract_first()` instead.

The code looks like this:

***myspider.py***

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider

class MySpider(Spider):

    name = 'toscrape.com'

    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/random']

    custom_settings = {
        'CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT': 100,
    }

    visited_quotes = set()

    def parse(self, response):

        quote = response.css('div.quote span.text::text').extract_first()

        if not quote in self.visited_quotes:
            self.visited_quotes.add(quote)
            yield {
                'author' : response.css('div.quote small.author::text').extract_first(),
                'quote' : quote,
                'tags' : response.css('div.quote div.tags a.tag::text').extract()
            }

        yield response.request
```

Then you run:

`$ scrapy runspider myspider.py -o out.json`

Comment: thank you @Guillaume, but this not gonna resolve my problem because that gonna cause redundant data, because the website can show the same quotes much time, so how to test if the data extracted is in the set extracted before?

Comment: @ekka you can simply use a set to remember the quotes you have already visited / seen, I've updated the code slightly